# General covering approximation

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, approximation-algorithms, linear-programming, integer-programming

Consider the following integer program (general covering):

$\min c \cdot x$ subject to

$Ax \ge b$,

where all entries in $A, b, c$ are nonnegative and $x$ is required
to be nonnegative and integral.

In Vazirani, it is an exercise to show that an $O( \log n )$-approximation algorithm exists,
where $A$ is an $n$ by $m$ matrix.  Could someone give me a reference
on how to do this?

In particular, I am interested in the case when $x$ is required to be binary, and in the use of linear programming to approximate.

Comment: If you really want the variables to be binary, it's a moderately challenging exercise.  Here's a paper about it http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1119632 that gives one method.  It can be simplified a bit.